# Git - upstream + feature branches + release branches

Tags: git

I was using the rebasing topic branches workflow http://www.golden-gryphon.com/software/misc/packaging.html

But because the local testers and admins don't like throwaway release branches, I need to move to a worklow with stable branches.

The only one that is acceptable is merging workflow. Now the issue is that I don't know how to work with dependent feature branches in this workflow. When rebasing, this was simple, with each patch I simply rebased all the feature branches that depended on this branch and everything was back to normal. With the merging workflow I can't rebase my feature branches, but merging seems a bit crazy for this.

Is there some better approach?

Comment: The link is dead, but it's at http://web.archive.org/web/20111230235724/http://www.golden-gryphon.com/software/misc/packaging.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With several long-term features, the model might look like this:

```
     o-----o  bugfix
    /       \
o--o--o------o------o  develop branch
       \      \      \
        o-o----o---o--o  long-term feature 1
           \    \   \  \
            o--o-o-o-o--o--o feature 2
```

Basically, you have a development branch, and merge bugfixes to you development branch. Long-term feature branch is base of development branch, and you update it by merging new changes from that development branch.

Similarly, you have a feature branch for reature 2, base on feature 1, and you update it by merging new stuff new feature 1 branch.

When feature 1 is done, you merge it back to develop, and update feature 2 from develop branch:

```
     o-----o  bugfix
    /       \
o--o--o------o------o---o---o  develop branch w/ feature 1
       \      \      \ /     \
        o-o----o---o--o       \
           \    \   \  \       \
            o--o-o-o-o--o--o--o-o feature 2
```

Comment: Looks kind of similar where I'm right now. Any tips for managing dependencies between the feature branches? I have 5 feature branches that are all used as a base for 2 other feature branches.

Comment: I guess not many people have that many branches to not be able simply sync them by hand. But I guess you can make some a script that would do all the syncing, and detect possible conficts and or breakage. The hardest thing is that you'll have to choose right branch for every patch (e.g. if you need some generic machinery for "feature 2" and you're going to need it for some other features, it's best to implement it in one of the ancestor branches.)

Comment: @Let_Me_Be It depends on how your repo (and software in general) looks like. From you comment I guess it is core->{feature1...5}->{otherfeatures1+2} [I really hate not to be able to put acii-art in comments]. If you have a central library like development branch, and your feature branches only consist of new features (=there is no core development), and also these feature branches don't share patches with each other, then the merge workflow is easy.

Comment: [And again SO cut me off. grml] The main problem is to keep the discipline to develop each aspect of the product in the correct branch, to avoid cherry-picking of patches between branches. Also a automated CI-like merge test system in the background is helpful to be alerted soon enough, if some changes in core or feature are going to break stuff along the merge chain.

Answer (score 2):

The main difference between a merge and a rebase workflow is that merges are invisible in the rebase workflow, but they still happen (you can see them in the reflog after the rebase). There are even much more of then using rebase, since for every new changeset of the to be rebased branch a merge of its own is performed, while in the plain merge workflow only one merge between the two branch heads are done.

A typical merge workflow looks like this:

```
             o-o-o--------------o         Release1+bugfixes
            /     \              \
o-----o----o--o-o--o---o----o-o-o-o-o--o  develop
       \     /               \     /
        o-o-o Feature 1       o---o Feature 2
```

Short-term features are developed in develop, long-term features get their own branches. Feature branches gets merged back into develop. For every release a branch is created from develop, and bugfixes are created on the release branch where the bug appeared. When a bugfix is done, it is merged back into develop.

A better explanation can be found at http://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/.

Comment: The problem is that I have several inter-dependent long-term feature branches. The workflow you describe is trivial (and pretty much part of my larger workflow).